# getting the accuracy of epsilon

Tags: python, function, square-root, epsilon

I'm trying to make a function that finds the square root of a number, without the square root command. That gets the answer to an accuracy of epsilon without any libraries, I have the basic code now

```
def mySqrt(b, e) :
    sqrt = b**.5
```

I've tried many different approaches to this but I can't figure out how to implement in epsilon `e`

Comment: what does 'That gets the answer with an accuracy to epsilon' mean?

Comment: Gets the answer to an accuracy of epsilon

Comment: Use search terms - python , square root, newtons method. Make a guess; check to see if it is accurate; make another guess based on what you learned from the previous guess; check it's accuracy; repeat ...

Comment: Isn't using the power operator `**` the same as using the `pow()` function?

Comment: epsilon would make the answer more accurate depending on the number you put in for `e`

Comment: `b ** . 5` is going to give you the answer to whatever precision the `float` type has. You need to implement your own algorithm.

Comment: The title should summarize the question so that when I read the title I see what it is about (and ideally get really interested in it) -- and when I read the question it is indeed that.  Here your title asks about epsilon-accuracy, seemingly in general, while the question is about the square root in particular.  This makes it unclear.  Another thing: when you metion "_different approaches_" perhaps you should say what. (All this is intended only as a well meant feedback.)

Comment: In general, you can calculate this with a series expansion (straight math), where for each added term you check whether the result is within epsilon. The recursive approach is good as well of course.  The `**` operator _is_ in a sense a "square root command"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), an iterative method to solve many equations to arbitrary precision. Applied to the square root the recursion goes as

[image]

or in Python code:

```
def my_sqrt(a, e):
    diff = e + 1  # random diff > e
    sqrt = 1.0  # start must not be 0
    while diff > e:
        sqrt = sqrt - (sqrt * sqrt - a) / (2 * sqrt)
        diff = sqrt * sqrt - a
        if diff < 0:  # make sure diff is positive without calling abs
            diff = -1 * diff 
    return sqrt

>>> my_sqrt(2, 0.00001)
1.4142156862745099
```

Admitted, this takes the epsilon into account after resquaring. So the result will actually be more precise than getting the root itself within epsilon.

Comment: how about without `abs` how would you do it

Comment: @nick Removed the `abs` call.

Comment: sorry to be a pain but what does this do `sqrt = sqrt - (sqrt * sqrt - a) / (2 * sqrt)`

Comment: @nick It implements the recursive step as laid out by the formula above. For more math details, pls see the linked wiki page.

Comment: what would be the difference from newtons way and just doing `** .5`

Comment: @nick `** 0.5` just calculates the  result to the best precision that `float` permits. And probably it does so much faster because the underlying C Implementation will be highly optimized. The numerical difference then depends on the epsilon you choose.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) to find the square root. As for accuracy checking, you would need the standard `sqrt` function, and then calculate `(expected-outcome)/expected` as your percent error.